# FedEx Rate Web services : How to disable Saturday_pickUp special service

Tags: fedex

I am facing issues a related to Saturday_PickUp of fedex and I am using web refences of fedex for calculating rates and shipment. Actually it is showing Saturday_pickup_surcharge even I am not initializing values for special pick on Saturday. As it is working fine for Saturday_delivery it should work for Saturday pick up too. As I have check there is no such IsSpecified boolean variable to enable or disable Saturday pick up. By default it is taking Saturday pickup special service and rate is increasing as per special service i.e Saturday_pickUp.

Please help me with that if you are aware with how to disable Saturday_pick_up. As I have provided the checkbox for Saturday pickup.

`private static void SetShipmentDetails(RateRequest request)
        {
            request.RequestedShipment = new RequestedShipment();

```
        #region |Setting Ship Date - Make sure to Saturday Delivery and Saturday Pickup : For saturday delivery uncomment code in SetPackageLineItems|


        DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2018-07-21T18:08:08", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", null);
        request.RequestedShipment.ShipTimestamp = oDate;
        request.RequestedShipment.ShipTimestampSpecified = true;     

        #endregion

        request.RequestedShipment.DropoffType = DropoffType.REGULAR_PICKUP; //Drop off types are BUSINESS_SERVICE_CENTER, DROP_BOX, REGULAR_PICKUP
        // If ServiceType is omitted, all applicable ServiceTypes are returned.
        request.RequestedShipment.ServiceType = ServiceType.PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT; // Service types are STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND ...
        request.RequestedShipment.ServiceTypeSpecified = true;
        request.RequestedShipment.PackagingType = PackagingType.YOUR_PACKAGING;//Packaging type FEDEX_BOK, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
        request.RequestedShipment.PackagingTypeSpecified = true;
        request.RequestedShipment.PackageCount = "1"; // change in rate according to package count 

        SetSender(request);

        SetRecipient(request);

        SetPayment(request);

        SetPackageLineItems(request,isCodShipment);

    } `
```

After setting sender , recipient and payment values 
here is the values for shipment.

`public static void SetPackageLineItems(RateRequest request, bool isCodShipment)
        {
            request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems = new RequestedPackageLineItem[1]; 
            request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0] = new RequestedPackageLineItem();

```
        request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].SequenceNumber = "1";
        request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].GroupPackageCount = "1";

        // Package weight information
        request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].Weight = new Weight();
        request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].Weight.Value = 20.0M;
        request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].Weight.Units = WeightUnits.LB;
        request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].Weight.UnitsSpecified = true;
        request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].Weight.ValueSpecified = true;

        request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].PhysicalPackaging = PhysicalPackagingType.TUBE;//BOX;
        request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[0].PhysicalPackagingSpecified = true;

        //// for saturday delivery
        //request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested = new ShipmentSpecialServicesRequested();
        //request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested.SpecialServiceTypes = new ShipmentSpecialServiceType[1];
        //request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested.SpecialServiceTypes[0] = ShipmentSpecialServiceType.SATURDAY_DELIVERY;

        if (isCodShipment)
        {
            SetCOD(request);
        }
    }`
```

*The code is commented for Saturday delivery because I am not using the date that comes on Friday*

If I will use Friday then we need to unhide that code. 

`// for saturday pickup
            //request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested = new ShipmentSpecialServicesRequested();
            //request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested.SpecialServiceTypes = new ShipmentSpecialServiceType[1];
            //request.RequestedShipment.SpecialServicesRequested.SpecialServiceTypes[0] = ShipmentSpecialServiceType.SATURDAY_PICKUP;`

The same way should be for Saturady pickup and as I am not writing code for saturday as it is hidden it should not include the saturday pick up charges

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried?

Comment: I have added the code.